# iOS 8 Keyboard Extension Layout

Tags: iphone, swift, layout, keyboard

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure out how to create a custom keyboard extension for iOS 8. I can do the functionality just fine and adjusting color really isn't an issue, **layout** however is the main problem. 
I've tried tons of crazy ways to figure out what the best layout would be such as checking the width of the input view or the width of the container app's view (neither of which are allowed apparently) and then determining what device it is so I can calculate a ratio for the size, height, and positioning of the keys according to the device's screen size and orientation.

So far the application is only using code and 0 nib files or story boards for the keyboard layout. If anyone can help me it would be absolutely awesome!

Right now there is a function for each key such as this for the q key

```
//Q Key

    func addQKey()
    {
        var qKey = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
        qKey.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Q", comment: "Q Key"), forState: .Normal)
        qKey.sizeToFit()
        qKey.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 14, width: (view.bounds.size.width / 6), height: 20)
        qKey.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Black", size: 20)
        //qKey.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
        //qKey.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1)
        qKey.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)

        qKey.addTarget(self, action: "didTapButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(qKey)
    }
```

This plugs into a method which then inserts the text

```
//TapButton Began

func didTapButton(sender : AnyObject)
{
    let button = sender as UIButton
    let title = button.titleForState(.Normal)
    var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy

    proxy.insertText(title!)
}
```

If you have any better methods or know how to fix the issue please let me know! Source code would also save my life!

Comment: can you printscreen how must look keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do manually layout, if so, I think you can first define some constants like

## define TOP_MARGIN 5

## define BOTTOM_MARGIN 5

## define LEFT_MARGIN 5

## define RIGHT_MARGIN 5

then define the gap between buttons and gap between rows(suppose they should be the same)

Then you can calculate each buttons frame using them with the keyboard width, in your UIInputViewController, self.view.frame should give you the keyboard frame.

For example, like Q

You first need to calculate the button width, and because we typically want the buttons to have the same width (or else), so button width for Q would be

int widthForQ = self.frame.size.width - LEFT_MARGIN - RIGHT_MARGIN - 9 * BUTTON_GAP

the same idea for height

int heightForQ = self.frame.size.height - TOP_MARGIN - BOTTOM_MARGIN - 3 * ROW_GAP

So your frame for Q is

CGRectMake(LEFT_MARGIN, TOP_MARGIN, widthForQ, heightForQ)

But I would suggest to use a nib with autolayout, it is really really fast and convenient.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Forgot to mark your answer. That helped a ton, thank you!